# Path Analyzer Site Maps

Tags: xconnect, path-analyzer

Running on Sitecore 9.0.2 in a multi site configuration and running into an issue when attempting to build a Site specific Map for Path Analyzer. All traffic is being recorded in the Global Maps -> Page Maps -> All Visits and reviewing the Reporting Database the SiteNames table is being populated as I would expect with a unique SiteName and SiteNameId per site I'm running.

[image: Sitename Records in the Database]

[image: Fact_PageMetrics Table recording to the correct SiteNameId]

From Marketing control Panel I navigate to Path Analyzer -> Maps -> Site maps, right click and insert a new Site map group. In the Site Name field I populate it with the same SiteName that's in my Sitecore settings which matches the records in the recording database. Looking at documentation on Sitecores site the Maps take 24 hrs to begin record / are able to be used in Path Analyzer.

[image: Site Map Configuration]

After 48 hours and local traffic of about 5 sessions a day the Map when selected reports that there is no data for the selected dates (past 2 days).

Site Specific Map
[image: Site Map Paths]
Global Map
[image: Global Map Paths]

Is there a set missing with System settings that I'm not setting up or is this a know bug with 9.0.2? Even just documentation on how to resolve this would be fantastic.

Thanks!
Ty

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a known bug in Sitecore 9.0.2. I opened a support ticket with Sitecore to find the resolve and steps here https://sitecore.box.com/s/7ld7eprcyjjp8z4hr5em6gyr6oakkmka. Be sure to also provide a site patch file containing all definitions of your sites on the processing server as well otherwise it will not resolve to the correct Site.

Answer (score 2):

Did you deploy the new site specific maps via workflow after those were created? To check, launch Workbox, activate "Path Analyzer Maps" workflow and see if you have any maps stuck in workflow. After those are deployed, check status of a given map in reporting database using SQL query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [reporting].[dbo].[TreeDefinitions]
  where DefinitionId='map-item-id'
```

Status=3 means it is done building. "1" means it is pending build. "2" means building. Other status would mean "error".

To check if you have any visits aggregated for a given map, run this query in reporting db:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [reporting].[dbo].[Trees]
  where DefinitionId='map-item-id'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Alex,
Looks like the all traffic map for the Site is in status 3 and when I directly query the Trees table with the ID there are 4 visits tied to that ID. Almost sounds like there's an issue retrieving the data for Sitecore to display. I'll try some digging in the query that Path Analyzer is sending to the database.

Comment: Strange, what's the visit count in Experience Analytics filtered by the same site? If you are getting expected numbers, then something is going wrong with path building during data pump. There may be errors in Sitecore logs on processing roles related to that.

Comment: Kept digging and found that when Sitecore is evaluating if the WebVisit inside of InteractionSiteNameCondition it's returning null. Was able to confirm that SOLR has the facet in the index so it's starting to feel like something isn't casting correctly back or not being set in the first place.